# removeChild() works but issues with null values

Tags: javascript, php, html, removechild

I was given this piece of code on here which works great to remove some selected values but for some reason I still get document.choice.field1.options[...].value is null or not an object
I basically don't want null or blank values, the code below worked but when values are changed in a drop down it doesn't work.  Can someone please help?

```
 document.choice.field1.removeChild(document.choice.field1.options[index])
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: It's usually not a very good idea to access elements based on global names. Post the HTML and hope someone has a better idea. As for null values, just check the length of the elements before trying to remove them.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?